# Email - From address is the logged in address and not the address that specified in 'from' attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-web-services, actionmailer

Below is the code for the mailer which sends the verification email:

**ApplicationMailer**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

**SendVerificationMailer**

```
class SendVerificationMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_verification(verification_id)
    @verification = Verification.find(verification_id)
    @email = @verification.email
    @token = @verification.token
    mail :from => "Support <support@domain.io>", :to => @email, :subject => "User verification code"
  end
end
```

In **production.rb** I have configured the `action_mailer` as follows:

```
  # Mailing preferences
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV["HOST_NAME"] }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :address => ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
      :port => ENV["SMTP_PORT"],
      :domain => ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"],
      :authentication => :login,
      :user_name => ENV["EMAIL"],
      :password => ENV["PASSWORD"]
  }
```

I used an account `info@domain.io` for smtp `user_name` and  `password`. When I send Email from local machine it is working fine and the from address in the received mail is `support@domain.io` in both **development** and **production** mode.

But, when the mail is sent from production machine in AWS the from address displayed as `info@domain.io` and not `support@domain.io` what I expect to be.

---

I am using **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** for deployment in which I have a `web server` and a `worker`, where the worker takes the attributes from **SQS** queue and send the Email.

Can anyone help me in fixing this.
Thank you..

Comment: Could it be that the SMTP provider only allows certain registered from addresses to avoid hosting spammers?

Comment: @max I use GMAIL.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. GMAIL does not allow you to use a different "from" address from the account address. It's an anti-spam feature.  You may want to consider a different provider. I've used www.speednames.com and been happy with them.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Ok, but then how it is working from local.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Sorry, I am not using Gmail in local thats why it works from Local. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Shall I post it as an answer?  You can accept it then.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Yes, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some email providers such as GMAIL (which you are using) do not allow overriding the `from` email address. It **must** be the email address of the GMAIL account holder.

If you have a requirement to change the `from` email address you'll need to look at other providers.

You may want to look at MailGun www.mailgun.com which is an email service that's very developer-friendly (even has sample Ruby code in its documentation) and allows up to 10,000 emails per month for free.